# vertically align a div and a span using css

Tags: html, css

please see the jsfiddle project [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wgsl2005/cckxkvov/) . How to horizontally align the box and the label?

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.legend {
  horizontal-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="legend">
  <div class="box" style="background-color: red;">
  </div>
  <span>Alabama</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean vertically align?

Comment: Align it like this? https://jsfiddle.net/Ahm7777/cckxkvov/2/

Comment: thank you. your way also worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can float the box instead of displaying it inline. There's a couple different ways to align these.

https://jsfiddle.net/cckxkvov/5/

```
.box {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.legend {
  horizontal-align: middle;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px; 
}
```

Comment: This is not a good way to vertically align elements in css. You are borking line-height on the legend for one thing, and there are already css properties designed to do exactly this (but better).

Comment: @SethWarburton I use this all the time for static content. Though I agree, there are many ways to achieve the same outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `vertical-align` property on the .box div would seem to make the most sense and cause the least issues.

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="legend">
  <div class="box" style="background-color: red;">
  </div>
  <span>Alabama</span>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't align quite well for me.

Comment: @AlexW.Can you elaborate on that a little? There are values other than `top` to try.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean vertically align? If you are simply trying to align, vertically, two div of unequal height then display: inline-block is the simplest and most effective method. You almost had it with your code, but float breaks it. Don't use float!

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 20px;
  width: 30px;
}

.box,
.legend {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="legend">Alabama</div>
```

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/27nwzmot/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use flexbox?

If you're trying to vertically align the two items within `.legend` then just apply these styles:

```
.legend {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Keep in mind you will need to apply prefixes for cross-browser compatibility.